# How to pass props from child component to its parent of parent?

Tags: reactjs, react-props, react-component

Suppose I have three components, where SubMain2 is inside SubMain1 and SubMain1 is inside Main. How would I pass props from SubMain2 to Main component?

**PROBLEM: TypeError: Cannot read property 'handleSubMain1' of undefined**

**Main**

```
class Main extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.handleSubMain1 = this.handleSubMain1.bind(this);
  }

 handleSubMain1() {
  console.log('received props from SubMain1 which is from SubMain2!');
 }

  render() {
     <SubMain1 handleSubMain1={this.handleSubMain1}/>
  }
}
```

**SubMain1**

```
class SubMain1 extends Component {

 constructor(props) {
 super(props);
 this.handleSubMain2 = this.handleSubMain2.bind(this);
 }

 handleSubMain2() {
  console.log('received props from SubMain2!');
 }

  render() {
     <SubMain2 handleSubMain2={this.handleSubMain2}/>
  }
}
```

**SubMain2**

```
Component SubMain2 extends Component {
   constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   }

   render() {
     this.props.handleSubMain2();
  }
}
```

I tried this approach, however I'm getting handleSubMain1 function is undefined. I even tried passing props from SubMain2 to Main component directly, however no luck.

Comment: You have invalid JSX in SubMain2, actually, in all your components. Passed props in components aren't `this.XX`. SubMain1 doesn't do anything with the `handleSubMain1` Main is trying to pass it. Same for SubMain2 with the callback it is passed from SubMain1.

Comment: apologize, fixed the issue regarding JSX.

Comment: SubMain1 is receiving the props from SubMain2, the problem is I can't pass the props from SubMain1 to Main. Or is there a way to pass props from SubMain2 to Main directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is the sandbox I made so you can see the console log : https://codesandbox.io/s/funny-chebyshev-n5srl?file=/src/App.js:63-717

here is the code in case you need it here:

```
class Main extends Component {
  handleSubMain1(arg) {
    console.log('received props from SubMain1 which is from SubMain2!');
    console.log(arg);
 }

  render() {
     return <SubMain1 handleSubMain1={this.handleSubMain1}/> 
  }
}

class SubMain1 extends Component {
  render() {
     return <SubMain2 handleSubMain2={this.props.handleSubMain1}/>
  }
}

class SubMain2 extends Component {
  handleClick(){
    this.props.handleSubMain2('any thing I pass as an argument I can access it in main');
  }

  render() {
     return (
       <button onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)}>
         Click me to send data to Main
       </button>
     )
 }
}
```

Comment: how can i pass props from SubMain2 to Main? that's my question

Comment: child -> parent -> parent?

Comment: You're absolutely right I misunderstand the question,
I don't know why you actually want to do this but I edit this answer to show you how @jyoo

Comment: I got it. I forgot to bind the function in one of the components... Thanks for your help!

Comment: I wrote it in my question, but not in my code.. haha

Comment: you're welcome , also don't forget to put ```return``` in your render functions ;) @jyoo

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use `this.handSubMainX` just use `handleSumbmainX={this.handleSubmainX}` and bind this in your constructor 
here is the result would look like:

Main:

```
class Main extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.handleSubMain1 = this.handleSubMain1.bind(this);
  }

 handleSubMain1() {
  console.log('received props from SubMain1 which is from SubMain2!');
 }

  render() {
     return <SubMain1 handleSubMain1={this.handleSubMain1}/> <-- 2 Change here
  }
}
```

SubMain1:

```
class SubMain1 extends Component {

 constructor(props) {
 super(props);
 this.handleSubMain2 = this.handleSubMain2.bind(this);
 }

 handleSubMain2() {
  console.log('received props from SubMain2!');
 }

  render() {
     return <SubMain2 handleSubMain2={this.handleSubMain2}/> <-- 2 Change here
  }
}
```

SubMain2:

```
Component SubMain2 extends Component {
   constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   }

   render() {
     return this.props.handleSubMain2(); // this function should return jsx
  }
}
```

Comment: sorry, but what's the changes you made?

Comment: I'll edit the code to show where I made changes @jyoo

Answer (score 1):

Props are only passed ***down*** to children. Each child component down the line needs to call the callback that was passed to it.

```
class Main extends Component {
  mainCallback = val => console.log("mainCallback", val);

  render() {
    return <SubMain1 handleSubMain1={this.mainCallback} />;
  }
}

class SubMain1 extends Component {
  subMain1Callback = val => {
    console.log("subMain1Callback");
    this.props.handleSubMain1(val);
  };

  render() {
    return <SubMain2 handleSubMain2={this.subMain1Callback} />;
  }
}

class SubMain2 extends Component {
  subMain2Callback = val => {
    console.log("subMain2Callback");
    this.props.handleSubMain2(val);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <button onClick={() => this.subMain2Callback(42)}>
        SubMain2 - click me?
      </button>
    );
  }
}
```

[image: Edit condescending-frog-jlwmo]